# libOpenDDS_Tcp.so: file not recognized: File format not recognized

Tags: linux, ubuntu-16.04, opendds

When I was trying to cross-compile code of Opendds to arm by `arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++` on Ubuntu 16.04, the following problem happened:

```
p/workspace/DDS/lib/libOpenDDS_Tcp.so: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
GNUmakefile.Messenger_Publisher:313: recipe for target 'publisher' failed
make[1]: *** [publisher] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/hadoop/workspace/DDS/DevGuideExamples/DCPS/Messenger'
GNUmakefile:38: recipe for target 'Messenger_Publisher' failed
make: *** [Messenger_Publisher] Error 2
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Try to do a `make realclean` and `make`, maybe some file got corrupted

Comment: it did not work, I am completely confused

Comment: 309 $(VBIN): $(addprefix $(VDIR), $(OBJS)) $(DEPLIBS)
310   ifneq (,$(LINK.cc.override))
311  $(LINK.cc.override)
312  else
313 $(LINK.cc) $(LDFLAGS) $(CC_OUTPUT_FLAG) $@ $(filter-out %.o,$^) $(VLDLIBS) $(POSTLINK)
314  endif
315 endif

Comment: Could it be that it is picking up a libOpenDDS_Tcp.so which is for your host system?